# handling double click on asp.net server side without javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this small demo to show my issue

markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="result"></asp:Literal><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="singleClickOnly" OnClick="singleClickOnly_Click" />
    <input type="hidden" name="CurrentRequest" value="<%= CurrentRequest %>"> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Dictionary<Guid, bool> CurrentGuidRequest 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Session["CurrentGuidRequest"] == null)
            {
                Session["CurrentGuidRequest"] = new Dictionary<Guid, bool>();
            }

            return (Dictionary<Guid, bool>)Session["CurrentGuidRequest"];
        }
        set
        {
            Session["CurrentGuidRequest"] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool UseCurrentRequest(string sGuid)
    {
        bool value;
        Guid guid;

        if (Guid.TryParse(sGuid, out guid) && CurrentGuidRequest.TryGetValue(guid, out value) && value == false)
        {
            CurrentGuidRequest[guid] = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public string CurrentRequest
    {
        get
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

            CurrentGuidRequest.Add(guid, false);

            return guid.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void singleClickOnly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && !UseCurrentRequest(Request.Unvalidated.Form["CurrentRequest"]))
        {
            return;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(4000); //simulate a long process
        result.Text += "1 ";
    }
}
```

mostly, I have implemented a CSRF tokens to deal with the double click.

the issue that I have, tested under internet explorer 9 (I cannot update it), is that on double click, when the page finish refreshing, the first click result would not be shown. The page wont show "1" in the literal since the final "refresh" would be the result of the double click.

is there a way to handle, server side code only, double click(ignoring the click itself) while showing the result of the first click?

Comment: What is wrong with disabling the click event using javascript?

Comment: @leppie some of my users doesn't have javascript and I have no control over them and I cannot force them to use javascript and I must make it work without javascript. so I'm stuck figuring out a way to do this

Comment: Without any JavaScript they are free to click as many times as they want. You can't control their browser from the server.

Comment: I am with @Nick. Educate your users.

Comment: @leppie, sadly I tried and like I said in my previous comment, I have to make it work without javascript. I think it is impossible to handle properly but I have to ask out here to see if someone else figured out a way to do this. At the end of the day I might change the return in the click even, inside the if, by a redirect to a page that say "sorry go back, verify your page/data again and click only once if needed" mostly because some code might have been already executed by the first click.

Comment: I didn't know ASP.NET would work with disabled javascript.

Comment: @VitorCanova, asp.net, mvc or webform, work nicely without Javascript. Javascript is always optional.